# Magento You Save Percentage on Product Page only if saving percentage is above certain number

Tags: php, magento

I would like to show You Save Percentage on Product Page only if saving percentage is above 10%. I am using this code which I found while searching google but unable to get the desired result. Please help me.

```
<?php
 $_finalPrice = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
 $_regularPrice = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice());
 if ($_regularPrice != $_finalPrice):
 $getpercentage = number_format($_finalPrice / $_regularPrice * 100, 2);
 $finalpercentage = 100 - $getpercentage;

 echo '<div class="salelabel">SAVE</br> '.number_format($finalpercentage, 0).'% </div>' ; 

 endif;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seams OK.
If you want the sale label only for a discount above a certain percentage just add an `if` statement around it

```
<?php
 $_finalPrice = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
 $_regularPrice = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice());
 if ($_regularPrice != $_finalPrice):
 $getpercentage = number_format($_finalPrice / $_regularPrice * 100, 2);
 $finalpercentage = 100 - $getpercentage;
 if ($finalpercentage >= 10) {
     echo '<div class="salelabel">SAVE</br> '.number_format($finalpercentage, 0).'% </div>' ; 
 }
 endif;
 ?>
```